# Suppress welcome message on bash remote command execution

Tags: bash

I'm executing some commands on remote server within a shell script like this:

```
ssh user@host <<ENDSSH
...
ENDSSH
```

Upon login I'm getting a standard server welcome message echoed. Is there a way to send it to `\dev\null` but to keep displaying the output of executed commands?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the `-T` trick? In any case, if the MOTD is static you could regex/whatever it away.

Comment: *What* "standard server welcome message"? There are any number of options for what that might be and how to suppress it (if possible) will differ depending on what the message is.

Comment: I mean `motd` message.

Comment: @DaveNewton `-T` has nothing to do with MOTD as far as I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `~user/.hushlogin` on the remote host. This will suppress output from the `login` program when `user` logs in (such as time of last login and any message of the day).

Comment: I was hoping to somehow do it from the client side but this is also (not so elegant but still) an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (for debian/ubuntu, your server might be different file) and turn the following setting to 'no'.

```
 PrintMotd no
 PrintLastLog no
```

Comment: `PrintMotd` is an `sshd` option, not an `ssh` option.

Comment: Indeed. You cannot supply arbitrary `sshd` options to the `ssh` command and expect them to do anything (other than potentially throw an error).